# inverse of fractional ideal in quadratic extension

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

I'm trying to solve the following problem :

> Let $K$ be a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathfrak{a}$ be a fractional ideal of $K$. Then inverse of $\mathfrak{a}$ is given by $$\mathfrak{a}^{-1}=\frac{1}{N(\mathfrak{a})}\mathfrak{a}'$$
>   where $N(\mathfrak{a})$ is absolute norm of ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{a}'=\sigma(\mathfrak{a})$ where $\sigma\in Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is nontrivial element. i.e. $\mathfrak{a}'$ is conjugate of $\mathfrak{a}$.
>
> *edited : Norm of integral ideal $\mathfrak{a}\subset O_{K}$ is defined by $N(\mathfrak{a}):=|O_{K}/\mathfrak{a}|$. For a fractional ideal, let $\mathfrak{a}=\lambda \mathfrak{b}$ for some $\lambda \in K^{\times}$ and integral ideal $\mathfrak{b}\subset O_{K}$. Then $N(\mathfrak{a}):=N(\lambda)N(\mathfrak{b})$ where $N(\lambda)=N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\lambda)=\lambda\lambda'$.

I showed that it is enough to show for integral ideal $\mathfrak{a}\subset \mathcal{O}_{K}$, but I cannot proceed more because I don't know how to deal with norm of ideal.

I know that norm of principal ideal is given by $N((a))=N(a)$ and I can prove the problem for principal ideal case using this. Is there any result about general case, i.e. $N((a_{1}, \dots, a_{r}))$? My conjecture is for any integral ideal $I$,  $N(I)=gcd_{x\in I} N(x)$ but I cannot prove it and even I don't know this will be helpful to solve the problem.

Comment: If you write $N(A) = A*A'$ then the identity is formally speaking a triviality. Thus you should make clear what definitions (e.g. for the inverse) you use and which results (cancellation law) you have already proved.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer I just edited.

Comment: What you need then is that $A * A'$ is principal and generated by the integer  $N(A)$. This is usually proved using modules.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer Can you give me more precise hints?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the proof of the equality of the two definitions for the norm of an ideal, one is the absolute value of the product of the Galois conjugates and the other is the index definition. From there it becomes trivial as then you literally have $\mathfrak{a}\sigma(\mathfrak{a}) = N(\mathfrak{a})$ so that your identity is tautological.

But this is just a matter of noting that the usual definition is as the determinant of a certain matrix, namely $\sigma_i(\alpha_j)$ where $\{\alpha_j\}$ is a basis of your ideal as a $\Bbb Z$-module. Using the definition of the product of two ideals as the ideal generated by the products of the generators, the rest follows quickly and is classical.

Comment: Can you give me any reference that includes proof of equality of definition?

Comment: @See-WooLee this should be included in most reasonable first texts on algebraic number theory (eg. Lang), and--in fact--should have already been covered in your class when one goes over the definition of the discriminant of a sub-module using the trace form (i.e. you should have discussed this during the definition of a field discriminant).

Comment: It seems that the Exercises in Chapter 3 of D. Marcus, _Number Fields_ cover the proof of the equality of the two definitions, especially Exercise 15(c).